# Check if JSON object is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to check if an object has any data in it inside of cities, so basically it would show true for data for this:

**JSON**

```
{"cities":[{"id":0,"client_id":"1","storename":"test","notes":"test","rejected":"on","offer":"test","time":1394457477525}]}
```

and false for this:

```
{"cities":[]}
```

Currently my code is incorrect as its not checking inside of cities just if its empty or not, is there any way I can adapt my code for it to work?

**JavaScript**

```
 if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(JsonData) == false) {
      $('#upload').show();
      alert("There is data");
 } else {
      $('#upload').hide();  
      alert("There is no data");
 }
```

Comment: It's an array, so just check for length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `JsonData` is a valid JSON

```
if (JsonData.cities.length > 0) {
   alert("there is data");  
}
else {
   alert("there is no data"); 
}
```

if `JsonData` is a string you need instead to parse it before as a JSON structure, using `JSON.parse(JsonData)` : see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for further reference

---

Note:
If you're not sure to always have `JsonData` or `JsonData.cities` available, you may create a fence for properties lookup (as suggested on [ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/archives/a-safety-fence-for-your-property-lookups)) in this way

```
if (((JsonData || 0).cities || 0).length > 0) {
   alert("there is data");  
}
else {
   alert("there is no data"); 
}
```

Comment: if you store your json in a `JsonData` variable, then `JsonData.cities` is the array

Comment: you have a `start?centre=1: 103` at the end of your json. this makes the whole json invalid (paste and copy your structure on http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: then I think you need to provide a fiddle that reproduces the error. I can't imagine what else is going wrong here

Comment: {"cities":[{"id":0,"client_id":"1","storename":"test","notes":"test","rejected":"on","offer":"test","time":1394458602054},{"id":1,"client_id":"1","storename":"","notes":"","rejected":"on","offer":"","time":1394458606774}]}  This was logged when i did console.log(JsonData); and it said there was no data .

Comment: could you try to `console.log(typeof JsonData)`?

Comment: string, was outputted

Answer (score 0):

check for `cities.length` its an array.